# Eclipse Text Not displaying properly

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, text-editor

I recently installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers: Indigo Service Release 2, on Ubuntu 11.04.

I created an Android project in it. But I am facing some issues with the text editor.

The following text

R.layout.main

is displayed as

R.layout.☐☐☐☐

That is, all the values assigned to the variables are not displayed.

If I open the file in Eclipse with 'Android Common XML Editor' or 'Android Manifest Editor' or any text editor other than 'Text Editor' (provided in Eclipse), I face the same problem.

When I copy & paste the text to some other editor outside Eclipse, or open it with 'Text Editor' in Eclipse it works fine, but there are no syntax highlighting etc in 'Text Editor'.

I tried changing the Character Encoding of the editors from the Preferences, but none of the encodings work.

How can I resolve the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your font settings.  I suspect that whatever font is being used doesn't handle *italics* properly.

Comment: Thanks! The font was set to Monospace, and it doesn't handled italics, as you pointed out.
I changed it to Liberation Mono, and it worked!!